# Determining Base case of a recursive java program

Tags: java, recursion

This code generates the powerset of a set of numbers. For example if we have (0,1,2) the power set is {(0,1,2),(0,2),(1,2),(0,1),(2),(1),(0),()}

```
public static List<List<Integer>> generatePowerSet(List<Integer> inputSet){
    List<List<Integer>> powerSet = new ArrayList<>();
    directedPowerSet(inputSet,0,new ArrayList<Integer>(), powerSet);
    return powerSet;
}
public static void directedPowerSet(List<Integer> inputSet, int toBeSelected, List<Integer> selectedSoFar,List<List<Integer>> powerSet){
    if(toBeSelected == inputSet.size()){
        powerSet.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(selectedSoFar));
        return;
    }
    //Generate all subsets that contain inputSet[toBeSelected].
    selectedSoFar.add(inputSet.get(toBeSelected));
    directedPowerSet(inputSet,toBeSelected+1,selectedSoFar,powerSet);
    //Generate all subsets that do not contain inputSet[toBeSelected].
    selectedSoFar.remove(selectedSoFar.size()-1);
    directedPowerSet(inputSet,toBeSelected+1,selectedSoFar,powerSet);
}
```

Why is the base case when toBeSelected == inputSet.size()?

Comment: You may use `Set<Set<Integer>>` to be sure to avoid duplicates, and to not have to remove element that you think you already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive code goes through valid indexes into `inputSet` list one-by-one, starting at zero. The current invocation uses `toBeSelected` as an index into `inputSet`, and passes `toBeSelected+1` to the invocation of the next level.

Therefore, the meaning of the base case is that there is nothing else to be selected, which happens when `toBeSelected` becomes invalid.

The last valid value of `toBeSelected` is `inputSet.size()-1`; `toBeSelected==inputSet.size()` detects the first invalid value of `toBeSelected`, serving as a base case for the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Because the code is trying to build the power set of an *n* element set, starting with 0 element empty set, then moving to 1 element sets, then moving to 2 element sets and so on.

When should this end? When you are finally trying to build a *n* elements set, because there is only one and that's the input set itself.